# Salesforce CPQ QCP issue in javascript code due to Eval function

Tags: salesforce1-app, quote, js

I have used Eval function in my QCP Code . My requirement is that we have one field on quote line which contains js code. I want to execute that js code dynamically from Qcp. we have around 500+ js code snippets based on the Quote line product.

So I used that eval function to do that. It worked for new Quotes. But while Amendments and Renewals its showing " Restricted Keyword found in Plugin Module".

Is there any work around at least ?

[image]

Iam passing snippet of js code as formula and variables object which indicates {fieldName1 :value, fieldName2:value}. field Names used in that formula or js code.

[image]

Comment: You're saying it works for some Quotes, but not for others. Would this not cast doubt on the assumption this is related to `eval`? As you have one Quote that causes the issue, could you paste the Javascript into your question - the one from the Quote Line Item and the `eval` you use? (You use Lightning Locker?)

Comment: Thank you for responding @FelixvanHove . In above I added js  code. I observed by commenting the eval function , then I didn't encounter any issue. Iam sure its because of eval only.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox  sfdcfox. can you please help me on this. Is this can solvable  by Lightning web security or api version ?

Comment: You can't @mention users that haven't interacted with the question, and trying to do so is considered very rude.

Comment: Sorry. I don't repeat next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eval may bring some issues with browser security , please try new Function instead of eval().[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the code as text instead of as an image. Images are not as accessible as text, and long lines of code make them practically unreadable.

Comment: @Apsara Thank you... It solved my problem.