# Does using Function (an Alternative to eval function in js) will impact Salesforce AppExchange Security Review

Tags: javascript, managed-package, appexchange, security-review, second-generation-packaging

In our Second Generation Managed Package, we are using Function() as an alternative to Eval Function as mentioned in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412782/salesforce-cpq-qcp-issue-in-javascript-code-due-to-eval-function) link to evaluate an expression in Aura Component. Does it have any impact in Salesforce AppExchange Security Review. As mentioned in the [Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_lightning_security.htm?search_text=css) we cannot use Eval function in a Managed Package, but can we use alternatives to the Eval Function?

Comment: I recommend you ask this question on the security review partner forum using your trailblazer partner login.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Phil W, I will ask this on the security review partner forum.